# Magento2 Settings

Tags: php, magento, magento2, administrator

When I toggle `Client Side Less Compilation` and save it on a Magento 2.2.2 site, it throws the following error:

> 500 internal server error

This is the log:

```
[Fri Jul 27 13:13:36.324051 2018] [:error] [pid 20125] [client 5.255.250.135:46655] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Magento\\Developer\\Model\\View\\Asset\\PreProcessor\\FrontendCompilation::processContent() must be an instance of Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\File\\FallbackContext, instance of Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\File\\Context given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php on line 90 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php:107\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php(90): Magento\\Developer\\Model\\View\\Asset\\PreProcessor\\FrontendCompilation->processContent('15859f29777d5d9...', '@import 'third-...', '', Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\File\\Context))\n#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/PreprocessorStrategy.php(74): Magento\\Developer\\Model\\View\\Asset\\PreProcessor\\FrontendCompilation->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\As in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php on line 107
```

I only have access to SSH and SFTP, how can I try to fix this?
I appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 0):

run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command from your magento root directory.

Comment: `[Exception]
  Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in
  /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 51
  2


setup:di:compile`

Comment: How I can return my config?

Comment: can you fix it if i let you ssh?

Comment: @DimaMorgunov yaa sure ...i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Find the path `dev/front_end_development_workflow/type` and if the value is `client_side_compilation` then change it to `server_side_compilation`. Clear all caches again and run `rm -rf var/cache/*`